# Build controller randomly gets unavailable, and has to be restarted manualy- TFS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-automation, coded-ui-tests, regression-testing

Our problem is sometimes when we queue a new build with ours cuid tests the build controller gets "unavailable". Then we have to login on the build controller server and restart the service manualy in tfs Admin Console. This seems to happening randomly. I have search the Internet but not found any relevant answers.
 Some suggested the firewall or two nic cards could be the problem, but it's not in our case.

---

### Eventviewer log:

> Logentry nr. 1.   (QTController.exe, PID 1568, Thread 21)
>   ControllerSpooledJob.AddMessage: Failed calling event listener
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.RemoteObjectContainer`1[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.IControllerEvents]:
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could
>   be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   110.11.170.140:2451   Server stack trace:     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress[] addresses, Int32 port)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket(AddressFamily
>   family)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket()
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.GetSocket()
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache.GetSocket(String machinePortAndSid, Boolean openNew)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.SendRequestWithRetry(IMessage
>   msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream,
>   ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)   Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.IControllerEvents.ControllerEvent(TestMessage
>   report)
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerSpooledJob.<>c__DisplayClass6.<AddMessage>b__3(IControllerEvents
>   eventListener)
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.RemoteObjectContainer`1.InvokeAsRemoteUser(Action`1
>   invoke)
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerSpooledJob.AddMessage(TestMessage
>   message)

---

> Logentry nr. 2.   (QTController.exe, PID 1568, Thread 46) User not in
>   the Admin group.

---

> Logentry nr. 3.   (QTController.exe, PID 1568, Thread 46)
>   ControllerExecution: Wrong run state during ReverseDeploymentComplete:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Exceptions.EqtException: Expected
>   state Completing, but actual state is Disposed
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.StateMachine`1.Verify(StateEnum
>   expected)
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerExecution.ReverseDeploymentComplete(Guid
>   runId, FileCopyFinishedReason reason)

Any suggestions, thoughts or experience regarding this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Build Controller or Test Controller?